# Can Not Create Album from GraphAPI

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api

Although it is possible to create album from the following privacy settings of Facebook,
the following error occurs if I use GraphAPI.

There is no specific description about the restriction in the API.
Please let me know if you have any idea to create the album from GraphAPI.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/

-the parameters to create album
name: albumName
privacy: {"value": "CUSTOM", "friends": "SOME_FRIENDS", "networks": "", "allow": "xxxxxxx", "deny": "yyyyyyyyy"}

allow:id of the particular friend (xxxxxxx)
deny: id of the family (yyyyyyyyy)

-Error Reason
"error": {
     "message":, "An unknown error has occurred."
     "type": "OAuthException",
     "code": 1
   }

Answer (score 1):

May You try this:

```
$page_token = $facebook->api('/'.$page['id'],'GET',array('fields'=> 'access_token'));
            $facebook->setAccessToken($page_token['access_token']);

            $page_id = $page['id'];


        $facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);

            $album_args = array(
               'message'=> 'test album',
               'name'=> 'Test Album'
            );



        try{

        $album = $facebook->api('/me/albums?access_token='.YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE,'POST', $album_args);
            print_r($album);                
            $albumID = $album['id'];




            }
            catch(FacebookApiException $ex){
                echo $ex;
            }
```

This should create an album on YOUR profile!